# CMOS Logic system

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, logic-level

When I was practicing logic circuit design using PMOS and NMOS, it's said that we have to use all PMOS for Pull Up Network (PUN) and NMOS for Pull Down Network (PDN). But, we know that for input voltage 0, PMOS will allow current flow, and for input voltage \$ V_{DD} \$ or logic value 1, NMOS will allow current flow.

If this is the case, why can't I solve this function $$ f=\bar{x_1}.x_2 $$ like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJhTr1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What kind of problem can this circuit create?
Is it any problem for bias voltage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a load resistor (say 10K) from output to Vdd, and make X_1 and X_2 low. Ideally, output should be 0.0V. You can figure out what it is (not 0V).

Now imagine a 10K load resistor from output to GND and make X_1 low and X_2 high. Ideally, output should be Vdd. You can figure out what it is (not Vdd).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYqROD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

"But we know that for input voltage 0 , PMOS will allow current flow and for input voltage VDD or logic value 1 , NMOS will allow current flow."

That is not true in general, it holds only when the NMOS source is at 0 and the PMOS source is at 1, which is not (always) the case in your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

if you interchange the positions of `PMOS` and `NMOS` transistor in a `CMOS inverter`,
it will become a `buffer`,and the `buffer` is not so good, because maximal output high level will be `VCC - Vtt`(`Vtt` is `NMOSFET's` threshold voltage), minimal output low level will be `VSS + Vtp`(`Vtp` is `PMOSFET's` threshold voltage).this is the reason that in digital electronics a buffer is made of two inverters, because the output voltage will close `VCC` or `GND`.